# Spring Boot 2.6.4 -> 2.6.6 : strange NullPointerException within Logback when logging a mock Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, logback

while upgrading from Spring Boot 2.6.4 to 2.6.6 , one of my tests (written in Kotlin), fails :

```java
    @Test
    fun shouldLogProperMessageIfNotAbleToHitAPI() {

        val configValidator = ConfigValidator(GitHubCrawlerProperties(SourceControlConfig(url = "someIncorrectURL",organizationName="someOrg")),mockRemoteSourceControl)

        `when`(mockRemoteSourceControl.validateRemoteConfig("someOrg")).thenThrow(NoReachableRepositories("problem !",mock(Exception::class.java)))

        val validationErrors=configValidator.getValidationErrors()

        assertThat(validationErrors).hasSize(1);

    }
```

the build passes with Spring Boot 2.6.4. It works in Spring Boot 2.6.6 when I run the test individually in my IDE, but fails during the maven build.

the stacktrace was not showing by default, but after surrounding the call by a try/catch, I am able to get it, and it points to Logback :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:99)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:62)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.error(Logger.java:538)
        at com.societegenerale.githubcrawler.ConfigValidator.getValidationErrors(ConfigValidator.kt:48)
```

Logback version doesn't seem to change, I still get v 1.2.11 .

Looking at Logback source code, in ThrowableProxy :

```java
        if (GET_SUPPRESSED_METHOD != null) {
            // this will only execute on Java 7
            Throwable[] throwableSuppressed = extractSupressedThrowables(throwable);
            
            if (throwableSuppressed.length > 0) {
                List<ThrowableProxy> suppressedList = new ArrayList<ThrowableProxy>(throwableSuppressed.length);
                for (Throwable sup : throwableSuppressed) {
...
```

note : I build with Java 11, so the comment saying in Logback source code that `this will only execute on Java 7` , seems wrong.

It seems that `throwableSuppressed` is null, and I get the NPE when `throwableSuppressed.size` is called.

The test passes if instead of using a mock in `NoReachableRepositories("problem !",mock(Exception::class.java))` , I use `NoReachableRepositories("problem !",Exception())`

I realize it's probably better to use a real Exception rather than a mock, so my problem is solved in a way (after spending 2 hours on this..).

However, I am curious : what could cause this issue after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.6 which should be a a minor change ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue was introduced in `logback:1.2.11` by this [commit](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/398aa4bd8f2bc0bb7f1465e8f7aca418c4464c15#diff-91f381102ba772e2944bcc4d01e615b39d0f366a91b9dddd05b29d736cbea9c1). It is tracked in this Jira [ticket](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1623).

`Logback` was upgraded to 1.2.11 from spring boot 2.6.5, you can refer to this [changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.6.5). So you would have encountered this same error if you upgraded to 2.6.5.

What we can do now is override the version of `logback` to 1.2.10 by adding this line in `build.gradle` file.

```kotlin
ext["logback.version"] = "1.2.10"
```

If you're using Maven `dependencyManagement` section for Spring Boot dependencies instead of the starter parent then you can try this:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- temp. override logback version for https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1623-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
<!-- ... -->
```

**Update**: Spring Boot 2 latest version (2.7.5) is still using `logback:1.2.11`.

Comment: You can also think about not mocking the exception. Then you don't have to override the logback version.

Answer (score -1):

If it is just for tests you can mock the LoggerFactory

```
        try (MockedStatic<LoggerFactory> loggerFactoryMock = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class)) {
            loggerFactoryMock.when(() -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(Logger.class));
            // your code
        }
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'when' in 'LoggerFactory'`